# how do I solve the Pylance(reportMissingImports)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, fastapi, pylance

I used `pip install fastapi` to download it in my virtual environment, in terminal but when I try to import from it it shows up as a missing import.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to install a package into your specific virtual environment, you need to first *"activate"* that environment. Likewise, if you want to run your script in that environment, you need to first *"activate"* it. You can do this manually or preferably let VSCode handle it for you.

In order to tell VSCode(especially the language server which is pylance) to use that environment:

1. Open up your Command Palette(press `ctrl+shift+P` or `f1`) and type : `"python: select interpreter"`.
2. Browse/Select your newly created python interpreter's path inside your venv.
3. Add `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true` to your `setting.json` file(It's also possible via GUI setting of course by searching for `python: activate environment`). This will automatically detect and activate your venv whenever you open your integrated terminal. Obviously If the path should points to a venv interpreter. (Note: you have to have a Python file opened in your editor).

---

You can also set your Python's interpreter path manually:

1. Create a folder called `.vscode` in your workspace.
2. Create a file called `settings.json` inside it.
3. Add these to `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "PATH_TO_VENV_INTERPRETER",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true
}
```

**Note**: What I normally do is, I insert a `"python.defaultInterpreterPath"` key to my **User** `settings.json` which points to my global interpreter. Then I create **Workspace** `settings.json` for each of my projects and add the same key which points to my venv's interpreter. Remember, workspace `settings.json` will overwrite user's `settings.json`.

This way whenever you open VSCode in a project folder it automatically knows it should activate your venv's interpreter(I told it to do so with `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment"`) and if you open VSCode in a normal folder it correctly use your global's interpreter.

[Difference between User and Workspace `settings.json`.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#:%7E:text=User%20Settings%20%2D%20Settings%20that%20apply,when%20the%20workspace%20is%20opened.)

Comment: This is it. This freaking line is the answer to all questions.

Comment: yep, adding "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true to my settings.json resolves this issue.

Comment: The first step has solved my issue. God blessed.

Answer (score 5):

Please select the appropriate interpreter for your running environment.

```
ctrl+shift+P
```

and then choose the one like picture.

[image]