# Import "speech_recognition" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm using an old code that used to work just fine but now that I'm starting to pick up where I left off it won't work, I already installed all the libraries that are needed for this project and restarted my Visual Studio Code, but my python won't recognize some libraries (the most important ones) this being "speech_recognition"

I installed and updated everything, and also restarted my visual code, but python won't recognize the libraries.
Does anyone know why this is happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You will need to make sure the package that provides `speech_recognition` is truly installed and accessible in the Python environment that you have active - see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019083/how-do-i-solve-the-pylancereportmissingimports).

Comment: to add on to toaster's comment, you may also need to make sure that the correct version of the packages are installed. Some libraries deprecate/relocate modules in newer versions that may be contributing to the issue.